# How do I access layer attributes from within QGIS' manageR plugin?

Tags: qgis, r, spatial-statistics

This is probably a fairly basic question, but searches for manageR come up with a lot of noise, and there's no manageR tag. What I'd like to do is load the attributes from a particular field of a layer in QGIS into a vector in manageR (equivalent of `x <- c(1,2,3,4)` if it was done manually). I can find a button to import layer attributes (when I press it, it shows `> manageR import function`), but I have no idea how to access them from within manageR thereafter. If it matters, the layer in QGIS is called `Aspalathus` and the field I'd like to access from R is called `mean`.

Comment: It could be that this is a bug, since a Google search on "> manageR import function" comes up with a number of seemingly unresolved issues (e.g. http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2010-September/009653.html). Confirmation on whether the above result is incorrect (i.e. whether pressing the import button should result in something other than `> manageR import function`) would also be appreciated.

Comment: I have run into this as well, and can attest to the frustration that comes from trying to Google manageR.  Please, any time you make a plugin, extension, etc that is R related please please please don't name it a common word.  Manage-R would have probably been fine.